# Возвращает пустой $_POST после AJAX запроса

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Я пересмотрела все возможные форумы, видео, сайты и т.д.

Имеется следующая html-форма:

```
 <form name="info_Application" id="info_Application">
    <div class="mb-3 row">
       <label for="dateFrom" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Введите начальную дату окончания:</label>
       <input id="dateFrom" type="date" class="form-control" name="dateFrom" value="<?= $_POST['dateFrom'] ?>">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1" id="FisFrdo" name="FisFrdo">ФИСФРДО</button>
</form>
```

Ajax-запрос:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#FisFrdo').bind("click", function () {
   let dateFrom = $("#dateFrom").val();
   $.ajax({
      url: 'https://www.univerprof.com/ru/administration-nmo/checkData.php/',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
             'clicked_btn': "FisFrdo",
             'check': "dateFrom",
             'dateBy': dateFrom
             },
      complete: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          alert("Данные отправлены ДАТАПО")
      }
   });
   return false;
   });
});
```

И в php я пытаюсь просто получить данные из поста:

```
<?php
var_dump ($_POST['clicked_btn']);
```

Возвращает array(0) { }.
У меня абсолютно больше нет вариантов и предложений, почему не работает :(

Comment: $out = $_POST; echo json_encode($out);

Comment: вместо `var_dump ($_POST['clicked_btn']);` пишите `echo $_POST['clicked_btn'];`

Comment: @АлександрСычёв, неа, выводит пустой массив(
если меняю файл, в котором сразу происходит отправка на сервер, то тут все срабатывает и данные получаю. Но когда меняю на файл, в котором хочу просто получить и вывести полученные данные на экран, получаю пустой массив

Comment: @АлександраВасильева не совсем понял вас

Comment: @АлександрСычёв когда в url ajax указываю другой файл, в котором происходит добавление в БД, то данные из формы добавляются. а когда меняю обратно на checkData.php, в котором просто пытаюсь вывести массив, он не отображается и получается пустой. в файле checkData.php хочу проверять данные из формы, и уже в дальнейшем работать с БД, но не могу ничего проверить, потому что условия не срабатывают, тк массив POST пустой

Comment: данные из формы отправляете на checkData, в этом файле у вас просто один var_dump? Вот так записывали $out = $_POST; echo json_encode($out);? Смотрели в нетворке уходят данные?

Comment: @АлександрСычёв, да, в файле checkData один var_dump, как вы говорили, я пробовала, echo выводит - []. В нетворке смотрела, Request Method: POST, Status Code: 200 и в FormData имеются переданные данные. А вот в файле checkData: Request Method: GET, Status Code: 200. и в Response: код страницы (<!DOCTYPE html> <html style="font-size: 16px;" lang="ru"> <head>......)

Comment: @АлександраВасильева добавил пример, можете посмотреть https://artsychev.ru/test.html

Comment: @АлександрСычёв data.responseText выводит целую страницу с шапкой и тем, что я указываю в php файле, т.е., если я в php вывожу `$out = $_POST; echo json_encode($out);`, то выводит json с моими данными, если указываю `echo $_POST['clicked_btn'];`, то выводит FisFrdo, почему и как это работает, и как получить данные в файле checkData

извините, за столь долгую и, возможно, настырную переписку, но мне правда надо в этом разобраться, а спросить как-то больше ни у кого

Comment: @АлександраВасильева у меня в профиле ссылка, можете написать по этому вопросу, а то что-то все не получается найти ответ

Answer (score 0):

@АлександраВасильева, вы упоминали некий другой файл, в котором данные из запроса нормально появляются. Этот файл находится в той же папке что и checkData.php?
Судя по вот такому ответу

> (`<!DOCTYPE html> <html style="font-size: 16px;" lang="ru"> <head>..`)

может быть неправильно настроен .htaccess